# Where are ProfilingActionFilter and ProfilingViewEngine in mvc-mini-profiler?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mvc-mini-profiler

I inherited a project that uses MvcMiniProfiler and now I have to go in and make some changes. I'm having trouble building the project because the following references are not valid (using MvcMiniProfiler 1.4)

`filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter(), 0);`

and

`ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ProfilingViewEngine(item));`

There was a `using MvcMiniProfiler.MvcHelpers;` but that reference didn't appear to exist so I changed that to `using MvcMiniProfiler.Helpers;` but that doesn't have these references.

I just installed this in VS10 using the library package manager. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the version. I don't know why but I was grabbing an old version and needed to update to 1.9.

Comment: you probably want to upgrade to 2.0 and rename that namespace to StackExchange.Profiling

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that in addition to the main MiniProfiler assembly, you have also installed the MiniProfiler.MVC4 nuget. This assembly (StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc) includes the ProfilingActionFilter and ProfilingViewEngine classes, both in the StackExchange.Profiling.Mvc namespace.

You can see these in action in the Sample.Mvc project.